# Trying to add CPAN Perl Modules to mod_perl on Apache CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, centos7, mod-perl, cpan

I am running Apache on Centos 7.

Some of the Perl modules that were not available via yum I have installed using CPAN in the custom location /export/home/www/perl5. I have used this custom location specifically to prevent the CPAN modules from interfering with anything installed by yum, or vice versa.

I then put this in my .bashrc:

```
export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT:/export/home/www/perl5";
export PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base /export/home/www/perl5";
export PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/export/home/www/perl5";
export PERL5LIB="/export/home/www/perl5/lib/perl5:$PERL5LIB";
export PATH="/export/home/www/perl5/bin:$PATH";
```

That worked great for running a locally built Apache, but when I try to run the Apache2 that comes with yum, I get this:

```
[Mon Jun 27 19:35:34.099272 2016] [perl:error] [pid 29077] Can't locate Apache/DBI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd) at (eval 3) line 2.\n
```

So the custom path has not been added to @INC for this Apache. I assume it isn't running from within my shell.

How do I get Apache to add this perl path?

Comment: What happens if you add `use lib /export/home/www/perl5` to your cgi script?   Or if you add `SetEnv PERL5LIB /export/home/www/perl5` to your apache config and restart apache?

Comment: or  `use lib qw('/export/home/www/perl5');` in the cgi script.  I suppose it depends on which behavior you want changed.  `SetEnv PERL5LIB /export/home/www/perl5` will add that for everyone using that server.